# Run a script inside docker container using octopus deploy

Tags: docker, octopus-deploy

Trying to do config transformation once a docker container has been created and the docker CP command does not allow wildcard and file type searches. While testing manually, it was found that it was possible to solve this issue but running the docker exec command and running powershell inside our container. After some preliminary tests it doesn't look like this works out of the box with octopus deploy. Is there a way to run process steps inside a container with octopus deploy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out you can run powershell scripts that already exist in the container with the exec command:

```
docker exec <container> powershell script.ps1 -argument foo
```

This command will run a script as you would expect in command line.